# Размер шрифта TextView

Tags: android

Здравствуйте! Хотелось бы узнать как можно реализовать возможность изменять размер шрифта во всей программе нажатием на кнопку и как для этого использовать параметр  `android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"`? (хотя выдает ошибку в этой строке)

Answer (score 2):

А Вы прописали сам размер? В `dimens.xml`:

`<dimen name="font_size">25sp</dimen>`

25sp, соответственно, меняете на необходимое значение.

При открытии `Activity` смотрите какой вариант размера Вы выбрали и меняете все необходимые размеры. Затем при нажатии изменяете размер и сохраняете выбор.

Comment: Ок, если я изменю 25sp скажем на 40 px то размер шрифта изменится. С этим понятно, а каким образом можно реализовать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку весь текст менялся к примеру на 50px или на 20px?

Comment: По нажатию задавать другой размер программно. `.setTextSize(R.dimen.font_size1);` Сохранять выбор и при открытии другой активити подставлять нужный вариант. P.S. в первом вопросе нужно было указать, что изменять будете во время работы.

Comment: Не совсем понял по поводу .setTextSize(R.dimen.font_size1); Если задача при нажатии на элемент списка изменять размер всего текста, то что еще нужно прописать?

Answer (score 1):

Разметка xml:

```
<TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="текст"
         android:textColor="#ffffff"
         android:textSize="20sp" />

<Button
         android:id="@+id/button"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Кнопка" />
```

Класс Android:

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        Button btnTextSize = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        btnTextSize.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textView.setTextSize(40); //значение присваивается в sp (px лучше не использовать) 
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Если ответ вам помог, то отметьте его как правильный.